# Use of semi-colons in If[]

Tags: syntax, conditional

This is the code in Mathematica:

```
h[x_] := (If[x > 5, Return[big]]; t = x^3; Return[t - 7])
```

I fully understand what the code does, with `h[4]=4^3-7=57` and `h[6]=h[7]=big` but I have the following issues:

1. `h[x_]` does not function if I remove the brackets `()` ie `h[x_]If[x > 5, Return[big]]; t = x^3; Return[t - 7]` , what is the function of `()` in the code?
2. Can someone also explain the significance of the semi-colons in this code, and what is it used instead of commas (which make the code not work). What are the benefits of using ; instead of , in code?

Comment: The code isn't that great; among other things, you have a global `t` in there which can be problematic if you're using `t` somewhere else. Try `h[x_] := Block[{t}, If[x > 5, big, t = x^3; t - 7]]` (but even that is not the best way to do it). Also, look up `CompoundExpression[]`.

Comment: function definition has a high priority. Without the `()` the function definition would end at the first semicolon. With the `()` the function definition is the whole line. The `If[]` tests x and potentially bails out with the value big. If it doesn't bail out then the `t=x^3;Return[t-7]` is all done. Be cautious with `Return` because people have reported problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

I might try to write the function a bit more simply as:

```
h[x_] := If[x > 5, big, x^3 - 7]
```

Then you can see it working by evaluating on the first 8 integers:

```
h /@ Range[8]
{-6, 1, 20, 57, 118, big, big, big}
```

Comment: Nit-picky: To get exactly the same functionality, you'd want something like `If[TrueQ[x > 5], big, x^3 - 7]`, so that `h[z]` would return `z^3 - 7` instead of an `If[]` statement.  But I expect the OP hasn't thought through that case yet and is assuming `x` is a real number.